# How to bin large number of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have continuous variable that ranges from 0-200k. I need to create bins that are 10k distance apart. For example

```
[0-10k), [10k-20k), [20k-30k),...
```

And label them this way 0,1,2,3....

However, using pd.cut I'll have to manually write these large number of bins myself. Is there any quick pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with `right=False` for left closed bins, for integer labels add `labels=False`:

```
r = range(0, 200000, 10000)

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[10040,50500,80000, 100000]})
df['b'] = pd.cut(df['col'], r, right=False, labels=False)
```

If possible, you can use integer division by 10k:

```
df['b1'] = df['col'] // 10000
print (df)
      col   b  b1
0   10040   1   1
1   50500   5   5
2   80000   8   8
3  100000  10  10
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem interested in a wildcard generation of bins and intervals. If so, please use `list(range(start,stop, interval))` to generate both the binning interval and label and allocate to your column.

**Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[10040,50500,80000, 100000]})
```

**Binning**

```
   df['bin']=pd.cut(df.col,list(range(0,210000,10000)), labels=list(range(1,21,1)))



   col bin
0   10040   2
1   50500   6
2   80000   8
3  100000  10
```